# Why is $T: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \ni f \mapsto (a_n) = (f^{(n)}(0)) \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ surjective?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Takeshi Saito.

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.
Let $T$ be a mapping such that $T: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \ni f \mapsto (a_n) = (f^{(n)}(0)) \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

$C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ are linear spaces.
$T$ is a linear mapping.

In this book, the author says that $T$ is surjective without a proof.

Why is $T$ surjective?

Comment: I don't know if there's an easy way to see this. [Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) should help in either case.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of @Monadologie works if you cut off the polynomials early enough. This is the proof presented on Wikipedia for Borel's lemma from a bird's view